# Share folder on local network with ubuntu

Tags: command-line, networking, server, samba

I try to share folder on ubuntu and connect to it through windows,
currently i know how to do it by these steps (which based on GUI):
https://linuxhint.com/share-folder-on-local-network-with-ubuntu/

but,
since I have a lot of computers I need to do it on, I want to build a bash file that will do it automatically on each computer i will run it,
I don't find on internet a way to share the folder with all the following checked (at "local network share picture" below) by a Command Line Interface.

these are the steps I wnat o do using CLI:

1. Choose the “Local Network Share” selection from the displayed list items:
   [Local Network share picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKUzB.png)
2. check the boxes displayed in the following attached screenshot and then click on the “Create Share” button:
   [Folder sharing picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWH5P.png)

Lets say i want to share the following folder:
/home/mkdahan/Desktop/Share_Folder

which terminal instruction can make this?

I tried to build a script that will share the folder /home/mkdahan/Desktop/Share_Folder but it still keep the folder "un-shared" as the GUI keep show, even after reboot:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo apt-get install smbclient

sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf ~/home/mkdahan/Desktop/Share_Folder


if sudo grep -Fxq '[Share_Folder]'  /etc/samba/smb.conf
then
    # code if found
    echo the '[Share_Folder] >> /etc/samba/smb.conf' exist at samba.conf
else

    echo [Share_Folder] | sudo tee -a /etc/samba/smb.conf
    echo path =  /home/mkdahan/Desktop/Share_Folder | sudo tee -a /etc/samba/smb.conf
    echo valid users =  salab  | sudo tee -a /etc/samba/smb.conf
    echo read only = no | sudo tee -a /etc/samba/smb.conf
fi


if sudo grep -Fxq 'server min protocol = NT1' /etc/samba/smb.conf
then
    echo the "server min protocol = NT1" exist at /etc/samba/smb.conf
else
    # append after [Global] the line "server min protocol = NT1"
    echo try to write to smb.conf    
    sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /home/mkdahan/Desktop/Share_Folder
    sudo sed -i '/^\[global\]/a\server min protocol = NT1' /home/mkdahan/Desktop/Share_Folder/smb.conf 
    sudo mv /home/mkdahan/Desktop/Share_Folder/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf 


fi

# Restart the samba
sudo service smbd restart
# check your smb.conf for any syntax errors
testparm
```

also, I see that if I share the folder through the GUI, the smb.conf file don't have the changes the script do, so i believe this is not the right method to do the requiered share (I used this method since this what i found on the NET).

**LongStoryShort:**
**How can i do using CLI the two steps can be done using GUI demonstrated above?**

No metter what thanks a lot!

Comment: Quote your `echo` string.

Comment: Thanks for your notes, I added "Long Story Short Section" to bold my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different files you could change to create a samba share:

#### Edit `/var/lib/samba/usershares/`

You can use the file manager GUI to do this, using `Local Network Share`. Or you can use the `net usershare add ...` command, but I find the syntax awkward (see [this post on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469977&p=14071704#post14071704)). Finally, you could edit the files manually if you know what you are doing.

This will add a "share" emblem on the folder being shared.

Check the created share using `net usershare info --long`

#### Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

There is no GUI tool to edit this, you must edit it manually.

This will not create a "share" emblem on the folder being shared.

Check the created share using `testparm -s`

---

I would advise creating the shares in smb.conf itself since you are altering the base settings there anyway with your "server min protocol" adjustment.

***Just remember not to share the same folder using both methods at the same time.***

Comment: Thanks a lot! it work.
method 1 you add here is equivalent to share through the GUI.